# How to divide textBox on column from db in sql query?

Tags: c#

How to divide textBox8 on value of Price

```
Int32 readSearch2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Price] FROM [Products] ", sqlConnection);
```

Comment: what do you mean by dividing it?

Comment: I need to divide value of textBox on value of column Price for example textBox value=50 and value of Price=10, i need to get 5

Comment: You know that `Products` may have many records, you want to get `textbox.Text/price` for all records?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding a SqlCommand Parameter, but as I mentioned in the comments, note that you may have many records in `Products` table and it will affect all prices (for all records):

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT @val/[Price] as Price FROM [Products] ", sqlConnection);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@val", SqlDbType.Float).Value = double.Parse(TextBox8.Text);
```